# How can I set different label and value for dropdown fields in Contentful

Tags: contentful

I'm new to Contentful and trying to create a simple dropdown field where I define a different value and label for each of the options. But I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I've created a dropdown by creating a *Short text Field*, setting **Appearance** to *Dropdown* and checking off *Accept only specified values* under **Validation**:

[image: Field validation settings]

But it only allows me to set the label part, which will automatically be used as value as well. Since a lot of my values translate to enums, it's weird for a normal user to have something like `TYPE_CAMPAIGN` instead of "Campaign" in a dropdown menu.

As an example of what I'm looking for, in [Advanced Custom Fields](http://advancedcustomfields.com) (WordPress), I can do it by typing `TYPE_CAMPAIGN : Campaign`, which results in `<option value="TYPE_CAMPAIGN">Campaign</option>`

Can a similar thing be done in Contentful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contentful DevRel here.

For the short text field we don't support this functionality. There are two ways to solve this use case.

### Create a content type for it

You could create a separated content type and solve the use case that way. Instead of using short text you can then reference entries of this separated content type. You can store your enum there and it also has the advantage that you can extend it with additional fields in the future.

### Extend the Contentful interface using the App Framework (or UI extension)

Another option is to leverage the [App Framework](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/extensibility/app-framework/). The Framework allows you to replace fields (, entries or even complete pages) with your logic. This way you could render a select with labels and values as it fits.

Comment: Has anything changed from the time you answered it? 

In my opinion, building a separate type or custom logic for choosing simple values is an overkill. It would be great if it was possible to define a list of value/label entities right in the field definition. So that I could provide meaningful labels and not confuse users with bare values.

Comment: Totally agree with you but don't think this changed. But disclaimer: I don't work at Contentful anymore so I might not be up to date.

Comment: The problem with a content type is that you cant set a default value on the reference field

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is how I did it:

    const TestLevel = stationContentType.createField('testLevel', {
      name: 'TestLevel',
      type: 'Symbol',
      required: true,
      validations: [specificValueRestriction([TestLevels.testa, TestLevel.testb, TestLevel.testc])]
    });

export enum TestLevels {
  testa = 'Test A',
  testb = 'Test B',
  testc = 'Test C',
}

export const specificValueRestriction = (specificValueRestriction: string[]): IValidation =>
({
  in: specificValueRestriction
});

And then I used datamappers to map the values to display the strings:

function mapStaffingLevelEnumType(testLevel: string) {
  if (testLevel== 'testa')
    return TestLevels.testa;
  if (testLevel== 'testb')
    return TestLevels.testb;
  if (testLevel== 'testc')
    return TestLevels.testc;
}
```